# Зависают и не решаются ячейки в Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, sympy

Беру простейший пример с использованием SymPy.
Блокнот висит в таком состоянии и ничего не происходит - в чем может быть проблема?
[image: Блокнот висит в таком состоянии и ничего не происходит - в чем может быть проблема?]

Comment: init_printing попробуйте сделать в отдельной ячейке. Сейчас не понятно на чем зависает - на импорте или init_printing

Comment: Попробовал - первая ячейка работает. Зависает именно на второй x=Symbol("x") - в этом месте.

Comment: Оставьте по одной строке в каждой ячейке и проверьте, на чем именно зависает. Возможно зависает на строке x - т.е. просто при попытке отображения

Comment: Зависает на строчке f

Comment: Попробуйте убрать init_printing, возможно из-за этого улучшенного принтинга зависает. Без него по идее должно тоже формулы отображать (но это не точно).

Comment: Да именно в init_printing и была проблема. Осталось только понять почему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

добро пожаловать на StackOverflow!

Код работает, я проверил в системе Google Colab. Возможно, проблема связана с локальным Jupyter Notebook. Попробуйте проверить логи блокнота либо переустановить его

Comment: Это по сути уточняющий вопрос, а не ответ. Уточняющие вопросы лучше писать в комментарии.